# EditText with InputFilter assigned / Decimal separator hidden in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm facing a very strange problem with an EditText with assigned InputFilter in an application I'm writing. The idea is, to have an EditText, which only accepts decimal numbers as input with a maximum of two decimal places and a decimal separator according to the user's locale settings. Here are the relevant pieces of code

The EditText in my layout

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="01234567890,."
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/category" >
```

The InputFilter implementation

```
public class MoneyFilter implements InputFilter {
    private String testRegex;

    public MoneyFilter(String decimalSep) {
        testRegex = "^\\d+\\" + decimalSep + "?\\d{0,2}$";
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        String s = source.toString();
        String d = dest.toString();

        String r = d.substring(0, dstart) + s.substring(start, end)
            + d.substring(dend);

        if (r.matches(testRegex)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

And the assignment of the InputFilter to my EditText in the related Activity

```
getValue().setFilters(
            new InputFilter[] { new MoneyFilter(decimalSeperator) });
```

*decimalSeparator* is read from the locale settings, and *getValue()* just calls *findViewById(...)* with some casting to the correct type.

In general my implementation seems to work exactly as supposed, but it shows one strange behaviour. When the decimal separator is already entered and the screen orientation is changed to landscape mode, it is hidden, all numbers stay visible. As soon as the orientation is changed back to portrait mode, it is shown again. I can even enter the decimal separator in landscape mode, although it will not be shown in the EditText, until the device is put back to portrait mode.

I could reproduce the behavior on my Android 4.3 device and in the emulator with API Level 18 and 10. Removing android:digits and/or android:inputType from the EditText, won't change this behavior, other EditText widgets without InputFilter behave completely normal, so I guess it's somehow related to that filter.

Several hours of research didn't bring anything useful up, so some help is appreciated :) If you need more information, or code, just let me know.

regards,

Hans

Comment: why not to do it without the inputfilter class and just do this all in that related activity `private String testRegex;`    `testRegex = "^\\d+\\" + decimalSep + "?\\d{0,2}$";`    `if(input.getText().toString().matches(testRegex)){ //do what u want} else{ //error}`.

Comment: I use the input filter, so the user can't even enter an invalid string. So for example after the second decimal place is entered, it is simply not possible to enter a third one. Or if the decimal separator is entered, you can't enter a second one. The keyboard input would by thrown away in those cases. If I'd do it in my activity, based on some event (focus change or whatever) I'd have to validate the input and put some error message on the screen. I could do that, but I don't like it from a usability point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are facing a known issue (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626) that Google is neglecting to fix from long time.

In Landscape mode, IME defaults to full screen or technically, ExtractEditText which doesn't honor the locale settings.

You can possibly resolve this issue by disabling ExtractEditText as follows : 
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

Comment: I've seen this bug, but did not identify this as a root cause for my problem, as it is not really locale specific (I could pass anything to my filter as decimal separator, regardless of the locale settings). But nevertheless, the workaround you've suggested works for me, as the EditText doesn't go to fullscreen anymore. I like that even better than the fullscreen mode, so you solved my problem and improved my app. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad it helped. I am bit bamboozled if this really improved the app because it really depends on screen sizes you are targeting. For smaller screen, this might add to poor user experience.

Comment: I've just checked in a 320x240 screen on the emulator, and it really works well, at least as good as in fullscreen. But the layout of this activity is very simple (two EditText using full screen width and two buttons on top of the screen). In general I'd agree to your concerns and won't use this as standard...